# Dynamic placement of Gmap pointers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typeerror

I have a positioning system I am working with that uses gmap3.net jquery plugin for Googlemap interactions.

I can place the pointers without problem when it's static, but having difficulty doing so dynamically, I know there is an error, I just can't seem to spot it.

I managed to get the eval working it was just missing some parenthesis, however, the eval only  detects one object, it seems to ignore everything after a comma.

So Here is the Javascript which initiates the map change:

```
    //Clear old map
    $('#map').gmap3('destroy').html('');

    var ajaxURL = BASE_URL + 'ajax/getPeopleNearMe/';

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxURL,
        data: { 
            filter: filter
        },
        success: function(data){

            $('#map').gmap3({
                getgeoloc:
                {

                    callback:function(latLng)
                    {

                        if(latLng)
                        {

                            //Found
                            $(this).gmap3({
                                marker:
                                {                       
                                    values:[eval("(" + data + ")"],
                                },
                                map:
                                {
                                  options:
                                  {
                                    zoom:12,
                                    mapTypeControl: false,
                                    navigationControl: true,
                                    streetViewControl: false
                                  }

                              }

                            });

                        } 
                        else 
                        {

                            //Not found

                        }

                    }

                }

            });

        }
    });
```

Then here is the PHP which is called on the get people near me function.

```
function getPeopleNearMe()
{

    $apiHandler = new APIHandler();

$result = $apiHandler->usersWithinRadius();

$json = json_decode($result);

$items = '';

if($json->value->results != null)
{

    if($json->value->numberOfResults > 0)
    {

        $count = 0;

        foreach($json->value->results as $result)
        {

            $items .= '
            {
                latLng:['.$result->lat.','.$result->lon.'], 
                options:
                {
                    shadow: 
                    {

                        url: "'.BASE_URL.'css/png/markerBg.png",
                        scaledSize: 
                        {
                            width:40,
                            height:43.5
                        }
                    },
                    icon: 
                    {
                        url: "'.$result->user->profileImage.'",
                        scaledSize: 
                        {
                            width:32,
                            height:32
                        },
                        anchor: 
                        {
                            x: 16,
                            y: 40
                        }

                    }

                }

              }';

            if($count <= $json->value->numberOfResults){ $items .= ','; $count++;} 

        }

    }

}


    echo $items;

}
```

The error I am getting is a type error:

```
TypeError: '
                {
                    latLng:[37.3323,-122.031], 
                    options:
                    {
                        shadow: 
                        {

                            url: "https://m.hollatme.com/css/png/markerBg.png",
                            scaledSize: 
                            {
                                width:40,
                                height:43.5
                            }
                        },
                        icon: 
                        {
                            url: "https://www.holla.com/img/resize/aHR0cHM6Ly9ob2xsYS1zdGF0aWMtaW1hZ2VzLnMzLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vcHJvZmlsZS84My8xMzYxODk2MDE2LmpwZw==/48/48/1",
                            scaledSize: 
                            {
                                width:32,
                                height:32
                            },
                            anchor: 
                            {
                                x: 16,
                                y: 40
                            }

                        }

                    }

                  },
                {
                    latLng:[37.3343,-122.049], 
                    options:
                    {
                        shadow: 
                        {

                            url: "https://m.hollatme.com/css/png/markerBg.png",
                            scaledSize: 
                            {
                                width:40,
                                height:43.5
                            }
                        },
                        icon: 
                        {
                            url: "https://www.holla.com/img/resize/aHR0cHM6Ly9ob2xsYS1zdGF0aWMtaW1hZ2VzLnMzLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vcHJvZmlsZS8xNDEva2F5c2FtcGxlLmpwZw==/48/48/1",
                            scaledSize: 
                            {
                                width:32,
                                height:32
                            },
                            anchor: 
                            {
                                x: 16,
                                y: 40
                            }

                        }

                    }

                  },
                {
                    latLng:[37.3323,-122.031], 
                    options:
                    {
                        shadow: 
                        {

                            url: "https://m.hollatme.com/css/png/markerBg.png",
                            scaledSize: 
                            {
                                width:40,
                                height:43.5
                            }
                        },
                        icon: 
                        {
                            url: "https://www.holla.com/img/resize/aHR0cHM6Ly9ob2xsYS1zdGF0aWMtaW1hZ2VzLnMzLmFtYXpvbmF3cy5jb20vcHJvZmlsZS8xNDIvMTM5Mzk0MF80NDcwMDYwOC5qcGc=/48/48/1",
                            scaledSize: 
                            {
                                width:32,
                                height:32
                            },
                            anchor: 
                            {
                                x: 16,
                                y: 40
                            }

                        }

                    }

                  },' is not a valid argument for 'in' (evaluating '"address" in O[L]')
```

I beleive the problem is that its seeing the data var as a string rather than an object.... But Have tried eval with no luck, not sure what else I could do... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because the browser interpretates the response as `text/html` instead of `application/json`. Make sure to specify the content type in your PHP script with:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```

Though this can cause problems on old versions of Internet Explorer (7 or lower). So another thing you can do is to tell your jQuery Ajax call that you expect a JSON response:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxURL,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 
        filter: filter
    },
    ...
```

Also, instead of construction the response as a string, you can simple create an hashtable/array and convert to JSON string with `json_encode`, something like:

```
$items = array();
foreach($json->value->results as $result)
{
    $items[] = array('latLng' => '['.$result->lat.','.$result->lon.']', 'options' => array('shadow' => '...', ...), ...);
}

echo json_encode($items);
```

This will avoid errors like the one you have just right there, since that's not a valid JSON string (the structure is something like `{...},{...},{...}` which is definitely not JSON since you're missing the `[` and `]`).

Finally, take off the `eval` function from your JavaScript, that has nothing to do with anything:

```
...
marker:
{                       
    values:data,
}
...
```

Comment: The format I was using was from: http://gmap3.net/en/catalog/10-overlays/marker-41 which is the plugin being used. I have tried this approach also, but the closest i have gotten is with what I am currently using, I just tried this approach again but with no luck, it's valid however the plugin does not plot the pointers...

Comment: I found out what he issue was , the lat and lon were being sent as a string, changed it from 'latLng' => '['.$result->lat.','.$result->lon.']' to 'latLng' => array($result->lat, $result->lon), and that sorted it, thanks for the help.